# radio button onclick function disable another function

Tags: javascript

I have two radio buttons and a group of checkboxes. One radio button allows the user to check all checkboxes and the other restricts the user to check one checkbox only.

```js
$('#r2').click(function() { //when one checkbox is checked then disable others
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked", false);

  $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').not(this).prop('checked', false);
  });
});

$('#r1').click(function() { //uncheck all checkbox
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked", false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" name="r" id="r1" checked> Can Choose all checkbox
<input type="radio" name="r" id="r2"> Choose 1 checkbox only
<br>
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
```

My problem is when I select the restrict radio button and select back the select all radio button the user can still check one checkbox only. How to solve this problem? Thanks

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/o09n7vwt/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to deregister the older `change` event listener with `off()`:

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').off('change');
```

Otherwise it won't stop listening for the `change` event, regardless which radio button you select.

**Working example:**

```js
$('#r2').click(function() { //when one checkbox is checked then disable others
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked", false);
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').off('change');
  
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').not(this).prop('checked', false);
  });
});

$('#r1').click(function() { //uncheck all checkbox      
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked", false);
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').off('change');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" name="r" id="r1" checked> Can Choose all checkbox<br>
<input type="radio" name="r" id="r2"> Choose 1 checkbox only<br>

<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
```